# How to add multi EditItemTemplate in ListView asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

as Title

in my code,there are 2 buttons  : "btnA" and "btnB"

---

**When I press btnA , I expect that the ListView will show "EditItemTemplate_Edit" and do not show "EditItemTempPlate_Reset"**

btnB is similar to btnA

---

I already added 2 EditItemTemplates in ListView like this :

```
                        <EditItemTemplate>

                            <tr class="EditItemTemplate" style="text-align: left;" id="EditItemTemplate_Eidt">
                                <td><asp:Label ID="Label_Factory" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("test1") %>' /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="EditItemTemplate" style="text-align: left;"  id="EditItemTemplate_Reset">
                                <td><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("test2") %>' /></td>          
                            </tr>

                        </EditItemTemplate>
```

I have already tried using script to set "display" -> "none" but it was not work

plz teach me how to make this work
thanks very much ~"~

Answer (score 0):

I actually suggest in these cases to not even bother with the templates.

You can actually use less markup, less code, and less messy UI for the user.

Why not just let them tab around - make as many changes as they want - almost like a Excel sheet.

then have ONE save button - and on un-do button.

That way:
They just edit - not all this song and dance to hit edit + save buttons
So less UI, less code, and you can just tab around on ANY row - just edit.
Much less code.

So, say we have this markup for the listview.

```
<style> input {border:none}</style>

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID"  >
  <ItemTemplate>
      <tr style="">
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Firstname") %>' /></td>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
      <td><asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>'  /></td>
                </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
     <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" class="table table-hover">
        <tr runat="server" style="">
        <th runat="server">Firstname</th>
        <th runat="server">LastName</th>
        <th runat="server">City</th>
        <th runat="server">Active</th>
     </tr>
     <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
     </tr>
   </table>
 </LayoutTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>

 <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn-primary" OnClick="cmdSave_Click1" />

 <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Row" CssClass="btn-primary" style="margin-left:20px" OnClick="cmdAdd_Click1"/>
 <br />
```

Note how MUCH LESS markup we have.

The code to load this lv looks like this:

```
    private DataTable rstPeople = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGrid();
            ViewState["MyTable"] = rstPeople;
            Session["test"] = "hello";
        }
        else
            rstPeople = (DataTable)ViewState["MyTable"];

    }
    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from People",
                                    new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();

            rstPeople.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

            ListView1.DataSource = rstPeople;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

So we now have this:
[image]

So, you are now free to edit - even tab around almost like a Excel sheet. SUPER easy to edit the data - no special buttons to edit/save each row.

Very nice for the user - no huge UI and clicking and messing around to edit.

And the save button code, again REALLY simple since we send the WHOLE grid edits back to the database in one simple edit!!!
(and ONE update operation for the WHOLE grid!!!).

Save button code:

```
    protected void cmdSave_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        // pull grid rows back to table.

        foreach (ListViewItem rRow in ListView1.Items)
        {
            int RecordPtr = rRow.DataItemIndex;

            DataRow OneDataRow;

            OneDataRow = rstPeople.Rows[RecordPtr];
            OneDataRow["FirstName"] = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtFirst")).Text;
            OneDataRow["LastName"] = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtLast")).Text;
            OneDataRow["City"] = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtCity")).Text;
            OneDataRow["Active"] = ((CheckBox)rRow.FindControl("Active")).Checked;
        }

        // now send table back to database with updates

        string strSQL = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, Active from People WHERE ID = 0";

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,
                                    new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter daupdate = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuild = new SqlCommandBuilder(daupdate);

            daupdate.Update(rstPeople);
        }
    }
```

So the trick? We persist the data table.

Then to save, you move grid back to data table, and then send the table BACK to the database in one simple update.

And the code to add a new row to the grid is ALSO very easy, we don't have to hit the database, but just add to the table, and then re-bind to the grid.

This code:

```
    protected void cmdAdd_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add a new row to the grid

        DataRow OneRow = rstPeople.Rows.Add();
        ListView1.DataSource = rstPeople;
        ListView1.DataBind();

    }
```

So, notice how we save world poverty, save buckets of code, save buckets of mark-up, and we save buckets of messy UI in which the user has to hit edit/save over and over JUST to edit a few rows.

So, save code, save money, same markup, save messy user interface, provide a MUCH better and seamless user experience.

What more could you want?

Note how we defined the data table at the web page class level - by persisting that data table, then we get all of the wonderful and easy to use benefits above - including MUCH less code, much less markup, and much less user interaction required to edit a few simple rows of data.

And we ONLY send ONE update back to the database to save all rows - all of the dirty work here is thus done by .net for you, and you even wind up with not only MUCH less code, but we hit the database MUCH less for the update.

I did not add a un-do-edits button, but all it would do is call loadGrid again, and that would just re-load the data gain - and thus un-do any of our edits.
(so a un-do button would be a good idea here.)